# erro que nao sei explicar o nome nem a causa

Tags: php

creio que nao seja um erro, mais uma ma estrutura nas verificaçoes das paginas recentemente adaptei uma url amigavel em meu site, ai decidi implemtar um sisteminha de pesquisa com ajax, na home do site ele funciona certinho como podem ver na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem quando eu vou para outra pagina do site e tento fazer uma pesquisa, ele acrescenta a `busca.php` e buga toda minha pagina conforme a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem sabe oque esta acontecendo ?

**index.php**

```
include_once("sql/config.php");
if(isset($_GET['url'])){

    $url  = $_GET['url'];

    $urlE = explode('/',$url);

}

if(isset($urlE[0])){

    $arquivo = $urlE[0];

}elseif(isset($urlE[0]) || isset($urlE[1])){

    $arquivo = $urlE[0];

    $post    = $urlE[1];

}


$paginas = array('contato');


//verifica se a pagina existe no meu diretorio

if(isset($arquivo) && in_array($arquivo,$paginas)){

    include_once "includes/$arquivo.php";

    echo "aqui";

}
//se nao existir nada na minha url, manda para a home
elseif(!isset($urlE[0])){

    include_once "includes/home.php";

    echo "aqui home";

}
//caso nao exista no meu diretorio, mais esteja cadastrado no banco de dados
else{

    include_once "includes/generos.php";

    echo "aqui generos";

}
```

> esta caindo no if que chama a pagina generos.php

alterei o meu ultimo `else` mesmo assim nao funcionou

```
else{

if($urlE == 'busca'){

}else{
    include_once "includes/generos.php";
        echo "aqui generos";
    }
```

}

antes eu estava chamando minhas paginas apenas com `include` ai pensei que o problema era esse, dei uma pesquisada e achei aqui mesmo uma explicaçao sobre `include`, `include_once`, `require` e `require_once` que o maniero fez, ai mudei tudo para `include_once`, mais nao resolveu meu problema

Comment: Mayron acho que esse seu controller do index está meio confuso. Provavelmente (não sei se é isso) a tela de busca está caindo em mais 1 IF  e por isso que provavelmente está duplicando e causando bugs inclusive no ajax. Dá uns `echo "aqui";` dentro dos ifs que você encontrará o bug.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho realmente esta caindo em um dos if, nao sei oque fazer, teria alguma soluçao ?

Comment: Eu precisaria entender melhor a sua url. Tem como você mostrar a url no caso que dá certo e a url nos casos que acontece o bug?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho a busca esta caindo no ultimo else, nao importa em qual url esteja, essa url que gera a pagina generos.php vem do banco

Comment: Acho que o problema é aqui: `if($urlE == 'busca'){ ...` na verdade é `if($urlE[0] == 'busca'){ ...` tenta assim.

Comment: Porque quando você dá um explode. Ele transforma a string em um array.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho mesma coisa, nao mudou nada, ue que estranho

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81553/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-mayron).